# Rocket.Chat iOS App after start

Tags: ios, rocket.chat

Is it possible setup Rocket.Chat iOS App to automaticaly going into specific room after start/restart?

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of the Rocket.Chat app on both iOS and Android it is not possible to have it take you directly into a room.

If you've had the app up previously it should bring you back to the room you were in.  But from a cold start the app will always bring you to the home page, and this is not currently configurable.

If you are looking for this to be added as a feature the best place to request it would be on the mobile projects repo found here: https://github.com/rocketchat/rocket.chat.cordova/issues

A potential work around to this would be to edit the home page layout and add a link to the channel you wanted to be able to jump directly into.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was suspicious that situation is like you described and idea with link at home page is not good, because link will open room in browser, not in App.